# How do I make video description active onclick?

Tags: jquery, iframe, video

I have a bunch of videos and wanted to know how to make the description active when that video is playing?

I have been able to add a hover state but it doesn't stay gold when that video is playing.

```
           <iframe id="vid_frame4" class="active" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cEQeHCG70Bw?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&rel=0" frameborder="0" width="454" height="255" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen></iframe>


            <div class="vid-item" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame4').src='http://youtube.com/embed/cEQeHCG70Bw?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=1&rel=0&autohide=1'" allowscriptaccess="always">
              <div class="thumb"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/cEQeHCG70Bw/2.jpg"></div>
              <div class="desc active" onClick=".addClass(active)">Directions for Use</div>
            </div>

            <div class="vid-item" onClick="document.getElementById('vid_frame4').src='http://youtube.com/embed/dPxKQ7uh6xg?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=1&rel=0&autohide=1'" allowscriptaccess="always">
              <div class="thumb"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/dPxKQ7uh6xg/2.jpg"></div>
              <div class="desc">Cup Size Programming</div>
            </div>

   .vid-item {
        width: 212px;
        height: 119px;
        float: left;
        margin: 15px 30px 0px 0;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .thumb {
        /*position: relative;*/
        overflow:hidden;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .thumb img {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: -20px;
    }

    .vid-item .desc {
        color: #000000;
        margin-top:5px;
        height:30px;
        float:left;
        text-align:left;
    }

    .vid-item .desc:hover, .vid-item .desc:active {
        color: #c79b4c;
        margin-top:5px;
        height:30px;
        float:left;
        text-align:left;
    }

    .vid-item:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Here's the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/designstreet1/awbyf1h5/

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Do you want the state to be active BOTH on hover and when the video is playing or just when the video is playing?

Comment: I want the hover state to stay the same but when that video is playing I want the text to stay gold

Comment: You have also tagged this question with jQuery... are you using any jQuery in this? If you site does not contain the jQuery library then you will be using JavaScript

Comment: My site is using jquery 1.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the ability to use jQuery, I would suggest taking all of your scripting outside of your HTML and either putting it into `<script>` tags or an external `.js` file.

A few things to realize, with regards to your CSS is that you can use `:hover` with a parent element to style a child element.

For my example, I will be adding a class called `.active-vid` to your `.vid-item` element, as well as adding a `data` attribute to your HTML

So, you can set your CSS to:

```
.vid-item:hover .desc, .vid-item.active-vid .desc {
    color: gold;
}
```

For your HTML, get rid of the `onclick` attribute and use jQuery event handlers. I would setup my scripts like so:

```
var vidArray = ["http://youtube.com/Video1", "http://youtube.com/Video2"]

$(document).on('click', '.vid-item', function(){

    $('.active-vid').removeClass('active-vid'); //Removes the current gold class

    var index = $(this).data('vidIndex');
    $('#vid_frame4').attr('src', vidArray[index]);

    $(this).addClass('active-vid'); //Sets new gold class
});
```

Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="vid-item" data-vidIndex="0">
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/cEQeHCG70Bw/2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="desc">Directions for Use</div>
</div>
```

Your `data-vidIndex` should be set to the index for the element in the array

Comment: Thank you. Only problem now is that when I click on the second video, the first one stays gold. I'm not very familiar with jquery sorry.

Comment: @Dunshea ahh, yes, one slight error on my end. I never removed the gold class before setting a new one. Take a look at the edit. You should be OK now.